# JavaFx - is it possible to drag and drop an image to a shape (circle)?

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, geometry, shapes

I'm not sure if I can drag and drop an image to a shape (circle). I have tried it with "setupGestureTarget();" , ".setOnDragOver" and ".setOnDragDropped".

So far the drag and drop works only on the scene (HBox) but not on the shape(Circle).

I'm not sure if and how the drag and drop works on shapes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Post a simple example in the form of a [MCVE] showing what you have tried. It would probably help to clarify exactly what you want to happen when the image is dropped on the circle, too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and the hint that it is possible. I tried again and managed to solve it with the ".setFill(new ImagePattern(image, 0, 0, 1, 1, true));" . For the whole code see Answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Code below you can drag and drop an image from anywhere on your computer into a shape in your application.

And further, the shape can be moved around (see "enableDragging"):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    Circle circle = new Circle(100,100,100);
    enableDragging(circle);

    pane.getChildren().addAll(circle);
    root.getChildren().addAll(pane);

    circle.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            /* data is dragged over the target */
            System.out.println("onDragOver");

            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if(db.hasFiles()){
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
            }

            event.consume();
        }
    });

    circle.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            /* data dropped */
            System.out.println("onDragDropped");

            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

            if(db.hasFiles()){

                for(File file:db.getFiles()){
                    //String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String absolutePath = file.toURI().toString();

                    Image dbimage = new Image(absolutePath);
                    ImageView dbImageView = new ImageView();
                    dbImageView.setImage(dbimage);

                    circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(dbimage, 0, 0, 1, 1, true));         
                }

                event.setDropCompleted(true);
            }else{
                event.setDropCompleted(false);
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Drag and Drop Image from Pc into Circle");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();    
}

private void enableDragging(Node node) {
    final ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseAnchor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    node.setOnMousePressed( event -> mouseAnchor.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())));
    node.setOnMouseDragged( event -> {
        double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mouseAnchor.get().getX();
        double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mouseAnchor.get().getY();
        node.relocate(node.getLayoutX()+deltaX, node.getLayoutY()+deltaY);
        mouseAnchor.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));;
    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }   
}
```